# how compile opus-codel with g++

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation

Hello I've got my first program using opus-codec library and I wonder if there is another way to compile it without passing by cmake. Such as the g++ command for example. Which flags should I use ?

Answer (score 1):

cmake is not a compiler, it is a tool for managing the build process. To compile your files, you are already using a compiler (g++ may be) which is called by the build files created by cmake.
For example when you run `cmake` command on a linux, you will generate a **Makefile**. The when you run your `make` command it will call **gcc** or **g++**. To see the compilation commands, you can add `VERBOSE=1` to your make command.